# bottle rout with wild card disable the css style

Tags: python, css, templates, bottle

The bottle template lose its style element while using route with wild card

/post/

I am using bottle, and Python 2.7 with Pycharm

@route('/post/ ')
def post(post_id):

```
return template('post',title="Post",result="", post_id=post_id )
```

The route like / - index, /contact is working well

Comment: I'm confused. What style element? What wild card? I see neither of those things in your question. You need to provide more context for someone to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

this is my route

> @route('/post/') def post(pid):
>       return template('post',title="Post",result="", pid=pid )

@route('/css/')
def css(filename):
    return static_file(filename,  root='static/css')

template

Problem 
The css work for other templates except this